# How to create a virtual environment for python 2.7.x?

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

I have 3 versions of python installed on my mac-OSX. Python 2.7.6 came pre-installed with the machine. I installed python 3.4.3 before. Now I installed python 2.7.11 by downloading the pkg file from the website. I also installed pip and virtualenv.

```
$python
```

If I run the above command on my terminal, the following is returned:

```
Python 2.7.11(...)...
.........
>>>
```

indicating that the latest version of python is working.

However, I created a virtual environment using virtualenv using the following command:

```
$virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 venv
```

and activated it using:

```
$source venv/bin/activate
```

If I now run the python command in the terminal with the virtual environment activated, the following is returned:

```
Python 2.7.6(...)...
.........
>>>
```

What is the problem here? Why isn't the virtual environment using python 2.7.11 and how can I fix this? Thanks.

**Edit 1:**
If I run this command:

```
$python2.7
```

the following is returned:

```
python2.7.11(...)...
....
>>>
```

**Edit 2:**
Running this command:

```
python -c "import os;print os.environ.get('VIRTUALENV_INTERPRETER_RUNNING')"
```

returns None.

**Edit 3:**
I tried specifying which python interpreter to use for venv creation.  My python 2.7.11 is located in a directory called python 2.7 in applications. I ran the following command:

```
$virtualenv -p /Applications/Python\ 2.7 myvenv
```

The following error was returned:

```
OSError: [Errno13] Permission denied.
```

Comment: I think /usr/bin/python2.7 is not link to python 2.7.11, please run python2.7 to check the version.

Comment: @xfx : Updated with your instruction.

Comment: Please run python -c "import os;print os.environ.get('VIRTUALENV_INTERPRETER_RUNNING')" and tell me the result

Comment: @xfx: The result is None.

Comment: Please run virtualenv -v -p /usr/bin/python2.7 something and send me the result.

Comment: Once again, running python inside the environment created by your instruction runs python 2.7.6.

Comment: What's the output of  virtualenv -v -p /usr/bin/python2.7 something?

Comment: Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python2.7 and then it runs a lot of things and creates the environment.

Comment: Yes I know it's a lot of things,I just need see the output to tell which step goes wrong.

Comment: Nothing goes wrong. The environment is created properly. It just uses python 2.7.6 and not python 2.7.11 which is what I want. Unless thats not what you are asking, then I can paste the terminal code into a question edit.

Comment: Please send me via https://dpaste.de/

Comment: Here you go [link](https://dpaste.de/VXep)

Comment: Everything seems just fine. Can you show me the result of  "ls -al /usr/bin/python*"

Comment: [link](https://dpaste.de/W1Qe) Yes

Comment: All seems fine. Sorry I cannot help you, just cannot tell the reason.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`$virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 venv`
will use the Python interpreter in `/usr/bin/python2.7`.

If you want a different Python version in your environment then you have to specify the right path.

Comment: Alright I tried what you suggested. My python 2.7.11 is located in a directory called python 2.7 in applications. I ran the following command: **virtualenv -p  /Applications/Python\ 2.7 myvenv**. The following error was returned: **OSError: [Errno13] Permission denied.**

Comment: Worked like charm.... I had 3.6 installed and wanted to create a venv with some other version.