# How to create virtual environments for python 2.7 on Mac?

Tags: macos, python-2.7, virtualenv

I am on Mac and want to create a virtual environment for python 2.7. I did the following but can't know how to access virtualenv to create the environment.

```
(base) congmins-MacBook-Pro:spacy congminmin$ pip --version
pip 20.1.1 from /Users/congminmin/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)

(base) congmins-MacBook-Pro:spacy congminmin$ pip2 --version
pip 19.2.3 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)

(base) congmins-MacBook-Pro:spacy congminmin$ pip2 install virtualenv
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in /Users/congminmin/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (20.0.30)
Requirement already satisfied: filelock<4,>=3.0.0 in /Users/congminmin/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from virtualenv) (3.0.12)
Requirement already satisfied: six<2,>=1.9.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from virtualenv) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata<2,>=0.12; python_version < "3.8" in /Users/congminmin/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from virtualenv) (1.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: appdirs<2,>=1.4.3 in /Users/congminmin/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from virtualenv) (1.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-resources>=1.0; python_version < "3.7" in /Users/congminmin/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from virtualenv) (3.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: distlib<1,>=0.3.1 in /Users/congminmin/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from virtualenv) (0.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pathlib2<3,>=2.3.3; python_version < "3.4" and sys_platform != "win32" in /Users/congminmin/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from virtualenv) (2.3.5)
Requirement already satisfied: configparser>=3.5; python_version < "3" in /Users/congminmin/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from importlib-metadata<2,>=0.12; python_version < "3.8"->virtualenv) (4.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in /Users/congminmin/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from importlib-metadata<2,>=0.12; python_version < "3.8"->virtualenv) (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: contextlib2; python_version < "3" in /Users/congminmin/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from importlib-metadata<2,>=0.12; python_version < "3.8"->virtualenv) (0.6.0.post1)
Requirement already satisfied: typing; python_version < "3.5" in /Users/congminmin/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from importlib-resources>=1.0; python_version < "3.7"->virtualenv) (3.7.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: singledispatch; python_version < "3.4" in /Users/congminmin/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from importlib-resources>=1.0; python_version < "3.7"->virtualenv) (3.4.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: scandir; python_version < "3.5" in /Users/congminmin/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pathlib2<3,>=2.3.3; python_version < "3.4" and sys_platform != "win32"->virtualenv) (1.10.0)
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 20.2.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

(base) congmins-MacBook-Pro:spacy congminmin$ virtualenv spacy27
-bash: virtualenv: command not found
```

How to make the 'virtualenv' command available?

EDIT:
I don't want to use anaconda. I just want to create a virtual env for python2.7.

Comment: you can use `python2.7 -m virtualenv` or probably `/Users/congminmin/Library/Python/2.7/bin/virtualenv`

Comment: @AnthonySottile I works and thanks by doing python2.7 -m virtualenv

Comment: I think This question is already been answered here: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34649914/how-to-create-a-virtual-environment-for-python-2-7-x>

Comment: @learner420 my problem was different. I can't run the virtualenv command: "virtualenv spacy27"