# Inherited an AWS Lambda project. What does lambdazip.sh file do & where in AWS do I need to upload it?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, shell, aws-lambda, sh

**EDIT:**
So lambda function projects can be uploaded as zip files.
I think this lambdazip.sh is a shell script used to zip the project. I have been manually zipping the project through the Finder on my MacOS.
After I cd to my /bin, I run

```zsh
sh lambdazip.zip
```

But I get the following error:

```bash
stephenstilwell@Stephens-MacBook-Air bin % sh lambdazip.sh
lambdazip.sh: line 6: cd: /lib/python2.7/site-packages/: No such file or directory
    zip warning: name not matched: pypdftk*

zip error: Nothing to do! (/Users/stephenstilwell/Downloads/cl_boost-pdfgen-1.3.3-master/bin/dist/cl-boost.zip)
    zip warning: name not matched: bin

zip error: Nothing to do! (try: zip -r /Users/stephenstilwell/Downloads/cl_boost-pdfgen-1.3.3-master/bin/dist/cl-boost.zip . -i bin)
    zip warning: name not matched: boost*
    zip warning: name not matched: pdf_surveys

zip error: Nothing to do! (/Users/stephenstilwell/Downloads/cl_boost-pdfgen-1.3.3-master/bin/dist/cl-boost.zip)
```

So I've been given a zipped file with no real instructions or documentation on what to do with the codebase.
My task is to get this project all set up on AWS.
The AWS Services in use will be Lambda, S3, Api Gateway, Simple Email Service.

To my current knowledge, I think this .sh file may have been used to test the lambda function locally before deployment to AWS Lambda, but I'm not sure.

Does this file need to be uploaded to the lambda function?
Does it belong in a Lambda Layer?
What is its purpose and why did the past developer use it?

[image: Lambda Project Schema]

**lambdazip.sh**

```sh
#!/bin/bash
PYTHON_PATH=$VIRTUAL_ENV/..
BASE_PATH=$PWD


cd $VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
zip -x "*pyc" -r9 $BASE_PATH/dist/cl-boost.zip pypdftk*

cd $BASE_PATH
zip -r $BASE_PATH/dist/cl-boost.zip bin

cd $BASE_PATH
zip -x "*pyc" -r9 $BASE_PATH/dist/cl-boost.zip boost* pdf_surveys
```

Comment: Typo in your post: you meant `sh lambdazip.sh`. Given that you don't have much experience with Lambda, I recommend that you put this project aside and first learn how to deploy a very simple Python Lambda function that has some dependency e.g. pypdf. Then do the same thing but move the Python dependency to a Lambda Layer, then reconfigure the Lambda function to use the Layer. After that you will be in better shape to understand what's needed here.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what this lambdazip.sh does, and I think what I'm learning is: this shell script may have been used to zip the project, to prepare it for upload via AWS Lambda. What I can't determine is if the other files in the /bin directory were uploaded via Lambda Layers or not.

Comment: It's a build/deploy-time script that the developer wrote to zip up his project, ready for deployment to AWS Lambda. The original developer obviously used virtualenv and you should too. Also, the requirements.txt file will list the dependencies and you can install them into your virtualenv in the usual Python way with pip. Is this Lambda function actually deployed currently? Can you review its configuration to see layers etc?

Comment: I wish I could see how it was configured in AWS. This function was deployed on an inaccessible AWS account. Additionally, the codebase is written in Python 2.7 which was deprecated for AWS Lambda. I have attempted to update the codebase to Python 3.9 (latest release) but this may make the dependencies incompatible: pdftk and libgcj.so.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see `lambdazip.sh` is used to package dependencies from the project's virtual environment and from the project's base path.

What you probably have to do is enable `VIRTUALENV` for the project by doing something like `python2.7 -m virtualenv` or following this: [enable VIRTUALENV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34649914/how-to-create-a-virtual-environment-for-python-2-7-x). Afterwards you may want to install the dependencies in your virtual environment using `pip`. You should be able to run `lambdazip.sh` afterwards successfully.

Comment: Is this for local testing & deployment? I want this project to run in AWS Lambda. The dependencies I have right now are `libgcj.so.10` and `pdftk` They are binaries that I was able to produce through an EC2 instance of CentOS 6. I think I might need to upload these zipped as Lambda Layers, but I'm unsure? Do I do the zipping or does this `lambdazip.sh` do the zipping? I unfortunately received this codebase without documentation for how it was previously configured on AWS. From what I understand, Python 2.7 isn't even supported on Lambda anymore.

Comment: It believe they are Lambda layers, since they are separate zip files. Although, I don't think anyone might be able to answer this confidently.

Comment: `libgcj.so.10` and `pdftk` are binaries. I will uploaded each as separate lambda layers to see if it resolves my `import module not found` error.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a helper for AWS Lambda function creation.

In case Lambda uses only core Python libraries, it's possible to just copy/paste its code to code editor in AWS Lambda Web UI.

But if you need some extra dependencies, you have two options:

1. Put the dependencies into so-called AWS Lamda Layer (and then you can copy/paste the function code via UI, plus in Lambda settings you'll have to connect the Layer to the function)
2. Put everything (both the function and its dependencies) into a ZIP archive and upload it as a Lambda function

If you choose the second option, you'll not be able to tweak code in visual editor (which may be useful during debugging).

I suggest that the `lambdazip.sh` creates the ZIP file with the function and dependencies.

Comment: I know that this project uses an external library called PDFtk. It is inside my /bin directory, but I think it needs to be zipped and uploaded as a lambda layer to help extend the python library. When I upload the entire project as a .zip I get some errors like "import module not found." When you say `I suggest that the lambdazip.sh creates the ZIP file with the function and dependencies.` are you suggesting that the lambdazip.sh does the compressing of my entire project?

Comment: Look which modules can't be loaded and ensure they are present in Lambda's ZIP file. Or you can try to find some 'pre-baked' Layer for these modules.

Setting up Lambdas may be pretty painful, unfortunately.

Comment: I tried to run `sh lambdazip.sh` from inside the /bin directory but received an error. I have added it to my original post.